# How to provide aws credentials and region as a constructor variable in scala class

Tags: scala, amazon-s3, constructor, aws-s3-client

I'm very new to coding, still learning. Looking for some guidance here:

I am trying to read a S3 file for which I'm creating credentials and S3 client as below:

```scala
import software.amazon.awssdk.auth.credentials.DefaultCredentialsProvider
import software.amazon.awssdk.regions.Region
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.S3Client

val credentials = DefaultCredentialsProvider.builder().build()
val s3Client =S3Client.builder().region(Region.US_EAST_1).credentialsProvider(credentials).build()
```

I have s3 object read implementation code in my class called: S3FileReader

Is there a way to pass credentials and region (which are used to create S3 client) as a constructor class parameter, such that deafult values to be null/None.

example:

Case class:

```scala
import software.amazon.awssdk.auth.credentials.DefaultCredentialsProvider
import software.amazon.awssdk.regions.Region

case class S3ClientAttr(
  credentials: Option[DefaultCredentialsProvider] = None, 
  Region: Option[Region] = None
)
```

```scala
class S3FileReader(s3ClientVar:S3ClientAttr(None,None)) extends FileHandler{

    def this()=this() //--> no values default
    def this()=this(S3ClientAttr(None, "US_EAST_1") //--default, value
```

Use these parameters to create S3 client:

```scala
val s3Client = S3Client.builder().region($Region).credentialsProvider($credentials).build()
```